# Copy and overwrite Github Repo

Tags: git, github

I have a repo named `github.com/someorganisation/somerepo`.

A long time ago I copied it to `github.com/someorganisation/somerepo-copy`

Given that there has been a long time since this operation took place, I now want to force-copy/overwrite the entire `github.com/someorganisation/somerepo` to `github.com/someorganisation/somerepo-copy`

Do I have to empty `github.com/someorganisation/somerepo-copy` first?

Comment: Do you have anything in somerepo that you don't have in somerepo-copy?

Comment: Yes, `somerepo` has been kept up to date for months so it does include stuff which are not in `somerepo-copy`

Comment: Do you want to somerepo-->somerepo-copy or somerepo-copy-->somerepo? In the first case, does somerepo-copy have changes that sonerepo does not have?

Comment: Hi, Yes remove the files and folders from `somerepo-copy` except `.git` folder. and then copy each and every folder of `somerepo` to `somerepo-copy` except `.git` folder and then commit and push that commit to remote.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `somerepo-copy` at GitHub. — Note that there is very little point having two identical but separate repos at GitHub. If the idea is to track `somerepo` in another repo, *fork* `somerepo`. That way, the fork can easily stay in sync with `somerepo` and won't go "stale" like this.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to empty it. You can just follow these steps:

warning: we are about to overwrite *anything* that exists on `somerepo` with the contents of `somerepo-copy`, so make sure that's what you really want because there is no going back.

(on somerepo-**copy**):

1. `git remote set-url origin [remote-url]`, replace `[remote-url]` with the repository's remote url, without the brackets.
2. `git push -f`: assuming that both repos are almost commpletely different, we are using the flag `-f` to replace anything that exists on the remote server with whatever exists on your machine. If the repos aren't that different you could try using a regular `git push`.

after those 2 steps the folder `somerepo-copy` will be "linked" to the remote `somerepo`.

source: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-change-git-remote-url/